# IF/CASE in an outer join

Tags: mysql, sql

We have two tables that I need to join on where a column (which, at this point, I can't change how/what values are used in that column) aren't using the same value.  So depending on the value of the column in the first table, I need to join/select a particular value in the second table.  Here is an example (which obviously doesn't work) of what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT Alert.*, Comments.Comment FROM
Alert
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments ON Comments.ObjectId = Alert.ObjectId AND
CASE
WHEN Alert.ObjectType = 'U' THEN Comments.ObjectType = 'USER'
WHEN Alert.ObjectType = 'E' THEN Comments.ObjectType = 'EVENT'
END CASE
```

So I want everything from the Alert table and, if there are corresponding records in the Comments table, I want those, too.  But only for the appropriate/matching ObjectType.

I've tried this using both CASE and IF but I can't seem to get it to work.  Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CASE` statement is made to *return* a value, not to *perform an operation*.

Also change the last `END CASE` to just `END`.

Use that returned value to compare with in the join condition.

Try:

```
SELECT Alert.*, Comments.Comment FROM
Alert
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments ON Comments.ObjectId = Alert.ObjectId AND
Comments.ObjectType = 
CASE Alert.ObjectType
WHEN 'U' THEN 'USER'
WHEN 'E' THEN 'EVENT'
END
```

Comment: But in the OP's original query, it *was* returning a value (specifically, a boolean directly into the `ON` clause)... I don't see why this would work where his didn't (although yours is more concise).  Can you help me understand?  :)

Comment: @eggyal, I'm not an expert in all the details, but boolean expressions does not work as one might hope in all situations. If you have `a = b` that is a boolean expression that can be used in conditional logic, if-statements etc, but it does not return a boolean value that you can use or assign anywhere.

Comment: This doesn't work.  The error I'm getting is:

    "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
    to use near 'CASE'"

Is that proper syntax?

I'm running v5.5

Comment: @Christoph, I have only tested on SQL Server, it seems like the syntax differs a little bit on mysql, try replacing `WHEN 'U' THEN 'USER'` with `WHEN 'U' THEN SELECT 'USER'`, etc.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work, either.  It looks like the use of "THEN SELECT" is relevant only in a stored procedure (which I'm not creating).  Looking at the docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html, it seems like your original syntax should have worked.  But it doesn't.  I wonder if that is because the case statement is part of the OUTER JOIN and not part of the SELECT...?

Comment: Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case instead, might be as simple as changing `END CASE` to `END`.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo - `END CASE` is only used in procedural blocks.  As a construct within a scalar statement it is *(as you say)* just `END`.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo, well, duh, now I feel foolish.  I just assumed that it was kicking over the first CASE it came across.  Yeah, that's working exactly as I hoped.  Thank you very much for your continued assistance!

Comment: @Christoph: Can you confirm that your original query also worked with `END` instead of `END CASE`?

Comment: @eggyal, my original query did not work with either END or END CASE.  My test was inside the WHEN and apparently that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
SELECT Alert.*, Comments.Comment FROM
Alert
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments ON Comments.ObjectId = Alert.ObjectId AND
Alert.ObjectType = LEFT(Comments.ObjectType, 1);
```

It seems a lot simpler...

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, it seems that not all 'matching' values start with the same letter.  In this case, I would recommend designing an intermediate table with columns AlertType char(1) and CommentType varchar(50).  Insert each combination of TypeId, like U, User; E, Event; etc.  The you can modify your SQL to read

```
SELECT Alert.*, Comments.Comment FROM
Alert
LEFT OUTER JOIN Intermediate i on Alert.ObjectType = i.AlertType
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments ON Comments.ObjectId = Alert.ObjectId AND
Comments.ObjectType = i.CommentType;
```

Comment: Because there in one table the object type is a single letter ("U", "E", etc) but in the other table, it's a full word and several of those words start with the same letter.  Not the best thought out and I'd give much to be able to go back and put some sense in to the head of the original designer.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Strategies such as joining on `LEFT(x, 1)` obfuscate any index on the field `x`.  This means that the 'simplification' for programatic convenience come at the cost of significant performance.  The intermediate join (or use of CASE WHEN to simulate it) are *significantly* better options.

Comment: @Dems: You are right, the LEFT() option does decrease performance.  On the other hand, it should still be able to use indexes, as you are using the first character of the word, so that the index should still be ordered properly.  This would not be the case with a RIGHT() function.  Secondly, no indexes were referred to in the question, so it's premature to assume this column is indexed. Finally, the question only dealt with two rows, so performance may not be a big concern here, and is not part of the question.

Comment: I would suggest that you test this supposition.  From an algorithmic position you are correct, but from an implementation perspective this is not the case.  *Some* implementations are able to cater for `LIKE 'x%'` and generate an optimal plan to do exactly as you describe.  But my experience with MySQL is that neither option generates an index seek.  And it unfortunately becomes relevant because even if there are only two cases in question, they still generate a full scan on the `comments` table.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you handle this with a UNION.  In one union join the user comments in another the event comments:

```
SELECT Alert.*, userComments.Comment
FROM alert
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments usercomments ON userComments.ObjectId = Alert.ObjectId AND usercomments.objecttype='USER'
WHERE alert.objecttype = 'U'
UNION
SELECT Alert.*, eventComments.Comment
FROM alert
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments eventcomments ON eventComments.ObjectId = Alert.ObjectId AND eventcomments.objecttype='EVENT'
WHERE alert.objecttype = 'E'
```

You don't have to alias them they way I did - it just helps readability.

Comment: This would require a new UNION statement be added every time a new ObjectId is added... that won't scale well.